# BTRFS Balance taking 100% cpu and 100% I/O

Tags: linux, btrfs, suse

We have a SuSE 12, sp3 server (SLES, not openSuSE).  There is only one disk in use on the system, the root disk with several file systems under mounted with BTRFS.

We are seeing issues where a "btrfs balance" job starts in the middle of the production day.  This appears to lock up the server, although what appears to be happening is that the balance process is consuming 100% cpu and 100% I/O.

Since we only have the one disk, and since the reason for the balancing operation is to balance block groups across all devices, do we really need to run the balancing operation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since we only have the one disk, and since the reason for the balancing operation is to balance block groups across all devices, do we really need to run the balancing operation at all?

This is the primary reason. It's not the only reason.

My answer is somewhat anecdotal. I will describe two scenarios where `btrfs balance` was/is useful for me. In both cases the Btrfs filesystem exists on a single device. This is about home usage, still the answer may give you some clue.

---

The first device is about 1.8 TB. I have used the filesystem for few years. During the last several months the free space oscillated under 100 GB, I kept adding new files and removing some old ones.

One day I hit "no space left on device", it was a surprise. Traditionally I use `df` instead of `btrfs fi df`, the tool reported 0 bytes free. I removed some expendable files, few gigabytes, then `df` reported about 20 GB free. I was able to add new data again. At some point `df` jumped from about 20 GB to 0 bytes free. After this I managed to add some more data (megabytes rather than gigabytes) until I hit "no space left".

This repeated several times but I had to get rid of more and more files to keep the things going. The threshold, that was 20 GB when I first observed it, grew to about 120 GB. Eventually I allegedly had 120 GB of free space but I could only write few gigabytes before hitting "no space left".

`btrfs balance start …` helped. After it finished I successfully wrote about 50 GB to the filesystem.

See what [`man 8 btrfs-balance`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-balance.html) says about "making block group usage more compact" (`usage` filter, examples). Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1290109/432690), it's way more technical than my story.

---

The second device is my SSD. I notice `fstrim -v …` can report less bytes trimmed than I expect. Only after `btrfs balance start …` the amount meets my expectation. Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1310581/432690).

I don't balance my SSD often though. I invoke `fstrim -v …` once a week or so; and only when I acknowledge it trimmed "way too little", I know it's time to balance (and trim again).

---

So yes, you may need to run the balancing. The scenario with `fstrim` probably doesn't apply to your setup, but the one with "no space left" may. Few hints:

- Maybe you don't need to run the balancing very often.
- Consider running it not "in the middle of the production day".
- You probably don't need to run a full balance. The [example](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-balance.html#making-block-group-layout-more-compact) in `man 8 btrfs-balance` provides some insight. With `btrfs fi df` you can probably estimate if you need to balance yet and what `-dusage=` to use.

Comment: Thank you for the response and for you suggestions.

The balancing cron job comes with the SuSE SLES 12 load, and I really wasn't aware of it until yesterday.  And, since I wasn't aware of it, it was quite a surprise to me to find it running in the middle of the day.  I'll be fixing that to run some time at night that doesn't affect the application running on the server.

Thanks again!