# BTRFS: no space but plenty free, balance doesn't do anything

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs

I've got a BTRFS filesystem on four 20TB disks.  It used to be three disks and I recently added a fourth:

```
> btrfs filesystem usage /data
Overall:
    Device size:          72.76TiB
    Device allocated:         54.67TiB
    Device unallocated:       18.09TiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:             54.67TiB
    Free (estimated):          9.05TiB  (min: 9.05TiB)
    Data ratio:               2.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:      512.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID1: Size:27.28TiB, Used:27.28TiB (100.00%)
   /dev/sda   18.15TiB
   /dev/sdc   18.15TiB
   /dev/sdb   18.15TiB
   /dev/sde  109.00GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:59.00GiB, Used:57.70GiB (97.79%)
   /dev/sda   40.00GiB
   /dev/sdc   38.00GiB
   /dev/sdb   40.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:3.75MiB (11.72%)
   /dev/sda   32.00MiB
   /dev/sde   32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda    2.97GiB
   /dev/sdc    2.00GiB
   /dev/sdb    3.00GiB
   /dev/sde   18.08TiB
```

(Output now, after the things I've tried, described below.)

If I create a large file, I get an error:

```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=stufff bs=1G count=10
dd: error writing 'stufff': No space left on device
9+0 records in
8+0 records out
9317646336 bytes (9.3 GB, 8.7 GiB) copied, 39.0117 s, 239 MB/s
```

The usual recommendation I've read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1290086/btrfs-no-diskspace-left) and elsewhere is to run a balance on the filesystem, and I did.

Right after adding the new drive I ran this:

```
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1,soft -mconvert=raid1,soft --background /data
```

Since then, I've tried various variants of this:

```
btrfs balance start -dusage=0 /data
```

with increasing values for `-dusage` up to and including 100, and even

```
btrfs balance start /data
```

Some of these gave me a few gigabytes of space, but I never get anywhere close to the 9TB that should be free.

*Question: What do I have to do to use all of the available space?*